# Window.Open() - loaded file has JavaScript injected / not rendered

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, window.open

In some legacy Classic ASP code, we have the following:

```
    onClick="window.open(newIntranetPath + '/taskManagement/forms/<% =step1FileName %>?taskReporting=true&uniqueId=<% Response.Write(myRs("UNIQUE_ID")) %>','view_event','status=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=1');"
```

The file that is being loaded into that `Window.Open()` function is one that has JavaScript code (between script tags of course). But when the page loads in the new window, all that JavaScript is loaded as text!

It is like the `<script></script>` tags are completely ignored!

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the HTML source of `newIntranetPath + '/taskManagement/forms/<% =step1FileName %>?taskReporting=true&uniqueId=<% Response.Write(myRs("UNIQUE_ID")) %>`? (ie. the page opened in the popup)

Comment: Is the JS executed if you type the URL into the browser's address bar?

Comment: If the file extension is `.js` change it to `.asp` or `.html` otherwise the browser will always show it as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that instead of linking to a file directly, you link to an ashx handler file (passing the filename as a parameter) which gets the file and serves it with the correct mime type so that the browser knows what to do with it.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405894/content-type-when-serving-a-file-in-a-generic-handler) for setting up a generic file handler and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111687/setting-mimetype-in-c-sharp) for setting the right mime types.